# How to not use If statements in loops

Tags: java

I'm actually not feeling comfortable with a for loop like this

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
{
   if (connected) {
       // send data to a connected client
       // takes about 10ms
   }
}
```

`connected` can be false any time in another thread while loop is running.

I'm looking for a way not to have "if check" in each loop cycle. 
Do you recommend some efficient recommendation for that?

Comment: Use a while loop? Or events to trigger your code. But avoiding if statements is impossible.

Comment: You can make that boolean synchronize or you could make a try-catch block IF you can handle the error propagate to the top level, i.e Show error to a user.

Comment: Should the loop exit in case `connected` becomes false or should it continue and try again?

Comment: You could use a timer class and check the status periodically,  That would be preferable over a tight loop.  But a better way would have the connection source fire an event when it becomes available.  But somewhere you will need an if statement.

Comment: @RichardBarker, it's the using while loop. 
@TaseerAhmad then how to get rid of the if statement?
@RobertKock yeah loop exit `connected` becomes false
@WJS can you provide a sample code?

Comment: would you like to use the lease flavour of Java8?

see example here
=>


        IntStream.range(0, 20).parallel().filter(i-> isNull(i) || your condition).forEach(your action);

Comment: `while(!connected)` or `while(connected)`

Comment: Move that additional conditional test into the for loop test `for (int i = 0; connected && i < 10000; i++)`?

Comment: @DrewReese it's almost the same thing. Just the place of the "if" is another place?

Comment: @faraway There is a conditional test each iteration of the for loop if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @DrewReese can you let me know that?

Comment: @faraway I'm still not sure what you are asking me to let you know, but the conditional test for the for-loop can be any expression that evaluates to a boolean value. The `if` isn't really being moved, but the boolean logic is being combined with other loop controlling logic.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the inner `connected` boolean check with the for loop's iteration condition test:

```
boolean connected = true;

// here the loop condition is that connected must be true 
// and i < 10 must be true in order for the next iteration
// to be entered
for(int i = 0; connected && i < 10; i++) { 
  // business logic while loop conditions true
}
```

Below is a working JS example to demonstrate

```js
const funLoop = (connected = false, earlyIndexCut = 0) => {
  let i;
  for(i = 0; connected && i < 10; i++) { // [0-9]
    if (i === earlyIndexCut) {
      connected = false;
    }
    console.log(i);
  }

  if (i !== 10) {
    console.log('Disconnected early!');
  } else {
    console.log('Completed loop iterations.');
  }
}

funLoop(false, 10); // Disconnect early as loop didn't run
funLoop(true, 5); // 0,1,2,3,4,5, Disconnect early
funLoop(true, 9); // 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 Completed loop iterations
```